# How to find the %change of two tables for every row in r?

Tags: r

So I have two data tables that have exactly the same names and dates, for example table a has its lowest point at that month:

```
Date       companya companyb companyc ...company200
2019-01      7         5        3            ...
2019-02      4         4        1            ...
```

table b has the highest point at that month:

```
Date       companya companyb companyc ...company200
2019-01      10        15        20           ...
2019-02      5         10        40           ...
```

I want to find the % change from the table a to table b, I tried using Delt from library quantmod:

```
change<-bind_rows(a,b)%>% 
  group_by(Date) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(delt(.))) %>% 
  data.frame()
```

But this gives me a row of NAs and the absolute change:

```
Date       companya companyb companyc ...company200
2019-01      NA       NA       NA          NA
2019-01      .42      2        5.6         x
2019-02      NA       NA       NA          NA
2019-02      0        1.5      39          x
```

How would I find the arithmetic change so it looks something like:

```
Date       companya companyb companyc ...company200
2019-01      -.42        -2      -5.6         x
2019-02        0         -1.5    -39          x
```

Thanks for all your help! I really appreciate it!!

*if anyone is having my same problem please check out Duck's solution it worked! ***

Just to give additional information, my ultimate goal is to left_join another column at the end with the percent change of an index(which I also have the highs and low of and need to find the change) and compare it :
My index looks like this :

```
Data     Index
2019-01   -2.5
2019-02   -5
etc       etc
```

I'm thinking of left joining it so

```
df4<-merge(df3,index, by="Date")
```

So it should look like this :

```
Date       companya companyb companyc ...company200  index
2019-01      -.42       -2      -5.6         x         -2.5 
2019-02      0          -1.5    -39          x         -5
etc          etc        etc     etc          etc       etc
```

and my goal is to flag each column by see if the percent change of each company is more than -20% than the index, I'm thinking something like this:

```
Flags <-df5    %>%group_by(date) 
               %>% transmute ((diff(col(2:200)-index)>20~1,
                               diff(col(2:200)-index)=<20~0)
```

so it looks like:

```
Date       companya companyb companyc ...company200  index
2019-01      0        0       0            x         -2.5 
2019-02      0        0       1            x         -5
etc
```

Please let me know if my logic is ok!

Comment: How do you obtain `-0.42`? It is possible to do a native solution to your problem.

Comment: @Duck I think it comes from (10-7)/7 . (Second - First) / First in general but I don't understand why (5-4)/4 is assigned 0 ? It should be 0.25. Maybe a typo.

Comment: @maydin yeah, (last-first)first !

Comment: @Duck  sorry! it's a typo ! thanks maydin

Comment: Yes, I def think using transmute/mutate will be the best option, because you can just had it to your table B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using next data taken from your post you can reach the variations:

```
#Data

df1 <- structure(list(Date = structure(1:2, .Label = c("2019-01", "2019-02"
), class = "factor"), companya = c(7L, 4L), companyb = 5:4, companyc = c(3L, 
1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

df2 <- structure(list(Date = structure(1:2, .Label = c("2019-01", "2019-02"
), class = "factor"), companya = c(10L, 5L), companyb = c(15L, 
10L), companyc = c(20L, 40L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))

#Code
df3 <- as.data.frame(cbind(df1[,1,drop=F],(df1[,-1]-df2[,-1])/df1[,-1]))

     Date   companya companyb   companyc
1 2019-01 -0.4285714     -2.0  -5.666667
2 2019-02 -0.2500000     -1.5 -39.000000
```

It is not clear for me how you obtain `index` if you explain more I could update the answer.

Comment: wow!! Awesome!! thanks Duck It worked! my index is another table with high and low, let me update my question so you can get my better idea

Comment: @Michael Great! So I think `merge()` or `left_join()` could join the new table with your index table.

Comment: I just updated my question, does my following code looks correct?

Comment: Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @Michael Try this to merge `Merged <- merge(df3,dfi,by.x='Date',by.y='Data',all.x=T,sort=F)` I think the flags can be easily computed, look for `ifelse()` around stackoverflow and you will find the key :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understood the question properly. But as far as I understood, you are trying to do an arithmetic operation on dataframes and then trying to join another column to it for comparison. Here is what I think can be done with a test dataset.

The two dataframes are **a and b**, **index** is the index data used for comparison and **c** is the resulting dataframe.

```
Date <- seq(as.Date("2020-01-01"), length.out = 100, by= "day")
a <- data.frame(Date, CompanyA= 1:10, CompanyB= 11:20, CompanyC= 21:30)
b <- data.frame(Date, CompanyA= 101:110, CompanyB= 111:120, CompanyC= 121:130)
index <- rnorm(100, mean = 10, sd=1)
c <- data.frame(a$Date, (a[,-1]-b[,-1])*100/a[,-1], index)
```

Comment: Happy coding.. :)